# How to escape a line break literal in the HTTP header?

Tags: http-headers

In the HTTP header, line breaks are tokens to separate fields in the header.

But, if I wan't to send a line break literal in a custom field how should I escape it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are designing your own custom extension field, you may use BASE64 or quoted-printable to escape(and unescape) the value.

Comment: +1 - means you don't have to worry about out of bounds characters, what character encoding is in use, etc. The RFC822-native ways of encapsulating these things are horrible, fragile, and typically won't work in HTTP.

Answer (score 11):

The actual answer to this question is that there is no standard for encoding line breaks.

You can use any [Binary-to-text encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-to-text_encoding#Encoding_standards) such as URL-Encoding or Base64, but obviously that's only going to work if both sender and receiver implement the same method.

---

[RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#page-16) did allow to 'fold' (i.e. wrap) header values over multiple lines, but the line breaks were treated as a single space character and not part of the parsed field value.

However, that specification has been obsoleted by [RFC 7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2.4) which forbids folding:

> Historically, HTTP header field values could be extended over multiple lines by preceding each extra line with at least one space or horizontal tab *(obs-fold)*.
> **This specification deprecates such line folding** except within the `message/http` media type *([Section 8.3.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-8.3.1))*.
> **A sender *MUST NOT* generate a message that includes line folding**

A standard for line breaks in HTTP Header field values is not – and never was – established.

Answer (score 6):

According to [RFC2616 4.2 Message Headers](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html):

> Header fields can be extended over
>   multiple lines by preceding each extra
>   line with at least one SP or HT.

where SP means a space character (0x20) and HT means a horizontal tab character (0x09).

Comment: Don't expect the newline to come out in the parsed version your app may get though; this mechanism exists historically from RFC822 only to fold long header lines into 80 characters.

Comment: @bobince, this kind of funny rules really ought to be scraped though. They complicate things for no real good reason.

Comment: @Pacerier: agreed, there are too many funny little wrinkles where HTTP is unclear and headers are parsed inconsistently - the mismatch in interpretation between components can cause security issues. But it's too late to do anything about it now: the HTTP header syntax is unsalvageable, all we can hope to do it replace it with something better-defined in HTTP 2.0.

Comment: It seems they heard your cires. Line folding has been deprecated in [RFC7230 3.2.4 Field Parsing](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-3.2.4). _A sender MUST NOT generate a message that includes line folding (i.e., that has any field-value that contains a match to the obs-fold rule) unless the message is intended for packaging within the message/http media type._

Answer (score 4):

The idea is, that HTTP is `ASCII`-**only** and newlines and such are **not allowed**. If both sender and receiver can interpret YOUR encoding then you can encode whatever you want, however you want. That's how DNS international names are handled with the `Host` header (it's called PUNYCODE).

Short answer is: You don't, unless you control both sender and receiver.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a custom field how you escape it depends entirely on how the targetted application is going to parse it. If this is some add on you created you could stick with URL encoding since it's pretty tried and true and lots of languages have encoding/decoding methods built in so your web app would encode it and your plug in (or whatever you're working on) would decode it.