# New line not accepted in HttpHeader - Asp .NET Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, http-headers, asp.net-core-2.2

I get the following error when I try to add a message in a HttpHeader:

> Message [string]:"Invalid non-ASCII or control character in header:
>   0x000D"

My code looks like this:

```
public static void AddApplicationError(this HttpResponse response, string message)
{
    response.Headers.Add("Application-Error", message);
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Application-Error");
    response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
}
```

The value from "message" variable is this:

```
IDX10000: The parameter 'tokenDescriptor' cannot be a 'null' or an empty object.\r\n Parameter name: tokenDescriptor
```

I tried to add a " " character after new line, as I found on Microsoft Docs page but it didn't work:

> New line characters in header values must be followed by a white-space
>   character. [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.headers.httpheaders.add?view=netcore-2.2)

As a workaround I removed the new line from the message and it worked.
Is this the only solution?

Thanks,

Comment: You cannot do this. Why do you want to do this? Why don't you just use the message body or a status code, like everyone else?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to escape a line break literal in the HTTP header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/521275/how-to-escape-a-line-break-literal-in-the-http-header)